# Please show me how to use an if/else statement in combination with wp_enqueue

Tags: php, functions, theme-customizer

In my theme I have the following code in my functions.php to enqueue my my stylesheets.

```
function mytheme_styles() {
    wp_register_style('headerMobile', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/header-mobile.css' );
    wp_register_style('headerGeneral', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/header-general.css' );
    wp_register_style('headerDesktop', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/header-desktop.css' );
    wp_register_style('fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/fonts.css' );
    wp_register_script('headerMobileEngine', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/header.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'headerGeneral' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'headerMobile' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'headerDesktop' );    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'headerMobileEngine' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_styles' );
```

Users should have the ability to change the layout of the desktop header; the default one or the mobile version (slightly adapted for desktop). I therefore have created a copy of the css for my mobile which I want to register as `headerMobileLarge`.

In the customizer, I created a radio button, 'layout_header_desktop', which can be `regular` or `fullscreen`.

Now I want to load headerDesktop when it is set to `regular` or headerMobileLarge when it is set to `fullscreen`. I figured out I could do this with an if/else statement in combination with `get_theme_mod()`, but I do not get it to work. Please show me how I should rewrite the `mytheme_styles()` to do this! Thank you!

Comment: Never heard of css media queries?

Comment: Of course, but I do not know how I change (or remove) the min/max-width of a media query as the result of a customizer control, if it is just in a normal CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like the following should work. Uncomment the `var_dump` to double check you're getting the saved theme mod value you're expecting. If not, check the naming of your customizer setting and that it saved properly.

```
function mytheme_styles() {

  $theme_dir_uri = get_template_directory_uri();

  // enqueue common styles and scripts
  // wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src = false, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' );
  // wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src = false, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $in_footer = false );

  $header_layout_style = get_theme_mod( 
    'layout_header_desktop', // name of your theme mod
    'regular' // default value, if no saved mod
  );

  // var_dump($header_layout_style);

  if ( 'fullscreen' === $header_layout_style ) {
    // enqueue relevant styles and scripts
    // wp_enqueue_style( 'headerMobileLarge', $theme_dir_uri  . '/assets/css/header-mobile-large.css' );
  } else {
    // enqueue other styles and scripts
    // wp_enqueue_style( 'headerDesktop', $theme_dir_uri  . '/assets/css/header-desktop.css' );
  }

}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!